# Comparing indentically-labaled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to use data from one dataset to filter data in other one.
My data looks like:

```
ls.head()
UserID  Rating  ISBN13  GoodreadsID     Title   Author
18266   2146832     5   0060525592  275000  Fire and Ice (Warriors, #2)     Erin Hunter
18267   2119385     5   0060525592  275000  Fire and Ice (Warriors, #2)     Erin Hunter
18272   2117173     5   0060525592  275000  Fire and Ice (Warriors, #2)     Erin Hunter
18273   2117009     5   0060525592  275000  Fire and Ice (Warriors, #2)     Erin Hunter
18274   2106234     5   0060525592  275000  Fire and Ice (Warriors, #2)     Erin Hunter
```

and my second dataset:

```
data.head()

    UserID  Rating  ISBN13  GoodreadsID     Title   Author
150834  2131509     5   0143038419  19501   Eat, Pray, Love     Elizabeth Gilbert
59347   2113561     5   0374528373  4934    The Brothers Karamazov  Fyodor Dostoyevsky
37087   2122197     5   0316015849  41865   Twilight (Twilight, #1)     Stephenie Meyer
950201  2107691     3   044619817X  5931169     Santa Olivia (Santa Olivia, #1)     Jacqueline Carey
114404  2144218     3   0441015891  2233407     From Dead to Worse (Sookie Stackhouse, #8)  Charlaine Harris
1053208     2143953     4   0451463099  6582703     Unknown (Outcast Season, #2)    Rachel Caine
18290   2148946     5   0060525592  275000  Fire and Ice (Warriors, #2)     Erin Hunter
1585865     2140143     3   1594742812  4133366     The Curious Case of Benjamin Button: A Graphic...   Nunzio DeFilippis
1115470     2125069     0   0758234937  11796251    Cinnamon Roll Murder (Hannah Swensen, #15)  Joanne Fluke
484235  2108848     5   0553816713  15931   The Notebook (The Notebook, #1)     Nicholas Sparks
```

I want to use column ls['UserID'] and select all those user from the second dataset ('data').

I've tried:

```
data.loc[ls['UserID'] == data['UserID']]
```

...which gives me

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

I've tried both `sort_index()` and `reset_index()`.

Help would be appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(ls, data, on='UserID')
```

you can also use the ***left_on*** and ***right_on*** parameters of that method (pandas merge)

Comment: Good idea! What it didn't occured to me? :-)